# Installing AllegroServe

Tags: common-lisp

I am currently reading Peter Seibel's book "Practical Common Lisp" and am on Chapter 26 : web programming. On page 366, it says that "the first step is to load the AllegroServe code into your Lisp image. In Allegro, you can simply type (require :aserve). In other Lisps (or in Allegro), you can load PortableAllegroServe by loading the file INSTALL.lisp at the top of the portableaserve directory tree. Below were the 2 responses when I typed them in :

1. When I typed (require :aserve) , the response was "NIL" .
2. When I typed INSTALL.LISP, the response was Error: Attempt to take the value of the unbound variable 'INSTALL.LISP'. [condition type: UNBOUND VARIABLE}

I have posted this question both on LispForum and comp.lang.lisp but have not received any satisfactory reply, and Peter Seibel hasn't replied to my email. Would appreciate it if anyone can advise how to correct this error.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `INSTALL.lisp` from command line, not from your Lisp prompt.
But the simplest way would be to get it with [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/): `(ql:quickload "aserve")`

EDIT:

Also notice, that the filename is `INSTALL.lisp` (extension in lowercase).

To load from command-line with SBCL run `sbcl --load INSTALL.lisp` (in the directory, holding the file).

Or you can load it from your Lisp prompt with full path: `(load "<path-to-directory>/INSTALL.lisp")`

Comment: Hello Vsevolod, Where exactly is the command line ? The Lisp prompt is the black screen that has CL_USER(1) , CL_USER(2) I presume ? Thanks a lot , sorry for the nebbish question. Also, when I typed (load "<path-to-directory>/INSTALL.lisp") from the Lisp prompt, it says Error: "<path-to-directory>/INSTALL.lisp") does not exist,cannot load [condition type: FILE-DOES-NOT-EXIST-ERROR]. Thanks a lot, GY

Comment: By command-line I meant shell prompt (or CMD in Windows). Regarding <path-to-directory> - you have to substitute the real path in your system here.

Comment: Hello, This is kinda hard to understand over the Internet. Does anyone know of any videos where I can watch in explicit detail visually how to create a website using Lisp? I just want to create a single website with about 5 to 10 pages with my name as the domain name using Lisp. Thanks ...

Comment: You can start here: http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/#tutorials There's also a video, but its a bit outdated: http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=5632573512646119509

Comment: It seems quicklisp has removed portable allegroserver from it, don't know why. There is no search result: http://quickdocs.org/search?&q=aserver

Comment: @whatacold you mistyped the name (extra 'r' in the end). It should be: http://quickdocs.org/search?&q=aserve

Comment: Oh, thanks for correcting me. As for PCL, I think Allegro Common Lisp Free Express Edition maybe a better way for practicing the code in the book, aserve is included out of box. And Portable AllegroServer seems being out of maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your current directory correctly set, then at the Lisp prompt:

```
(load "install.lisp")
```

Comment: That one is correct i.e. running `INSTALL.lisp` from command line isn't.