# Can't get AllegroServe / Ironclad to work

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

### `(ql:quickload "aserve")` fails

I'm trying to install AllegroServe. According to http://quickdocs.org/portableaserve/ and to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519851/installing-allegroserve) the simplest way to get *aserve* would be to get it with quicklisp: `(ql:quickload "aserve")`

But `(ql:quickload "aserve")` fails yielding the following error in the debugger buffer:

```
COMPILE-FILE-ERROR while compiling
   #<IRONCLAD-SOURCE-FILE "ironclad" "src" "digests" "digest">
   [Condition of type UIOP/LISP-BUILD:COMPILE-FILE-ERROR]
```

Whereas in the REPL it says:

```
; Loading "aserve"
; caught ERROR: READ error during COMPILE-FILE: Symbol "BIGNUM-TYPE"
;   not found in the SB-BIGNUM package.  Line: 53, Column: 52,
;   File-Position: 2151 Stream: #<SB-INT:FORM-TRACKING-STREAM for
;   "file
;   C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\quicklisp\\dists\\quicklisp\\software\\ironclad_0.33.0\\src\\digests\\digest.lisp"
;   {25AFCD91}>
```

### What I've tried so far

Apparently ironclad is another package, a "cryptographic toolkit written in pure Common Lisp". I downloaded ironclad-v0.34 from http://quickdocs.org/ironclad/ and even found `digest.lisp` and `digests.lisp` in the ironclad folder which made me think that I am on the right track.

My problem is I don't no where to go from here. How and where do I "install" *ironclad*?

Quickdocs says

> [ironclad] comes with an ASDF system definition, so `(asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op
>   :ironclad)` should be all that you need to get started. The testsuite
>   can be run by substituting asdf:test-op for asdf:load-op in the form
>   above.

but since I'm not familiar with asdf I don't know what to make of it.

Am I even on the right track? Is installing the ironclad package the right way to make the error `COMPILE-FILE-ERROR while compiling #<IRONCLAD-SOURCE-FILE "ironclad" "src" "digests" "digest">`go away? If so what do I do with the ironclad-v0.34 folder?

(I'm using sbcl on a windows 10 machine.)

Comment: There's probably some more output regarding the error wherever ql is printing to (such as the repl-buffer in Emacs).

Comment: I added the repl output regarding the error.

Comment: Seems like the error is caused by Ironclad using `SB-BIGNUM:BIGNUM-TYPE`, which was removed from SBCL. This appears to be [fixed](https://github.com/froydnj/ironclad/commit/8807f305c79a07a22baa7c1f73fc12e2b4f24046), so installing the latest version should work. See if putting the newest version to your `quicklisp/local-projects/` directory and doing `(ql:register-local-projects)` helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jkiiski leading me down the right path I was able to install *aserve*. The problem was indeed an old version of *ironclad* which, as @jkiiski pointed out, was using `SB-BIGNUM:BIGNUM-TYPE` which had been removed from SBCL.

#### However, the way I updated *ironclad* is probably *NOT*(!) a good way because I did it all manually (error prone).

Not knowing how quicklisp works exactly I searched for every occurence of ironclad-0.33.0 and replaced it with ironclad-v0.34, which meant replacing

- the *.../dists/quicklisp/software/ironclad-0.33.0* folder with *.../dists/quicklisp/software/ironclad-v0.34*
- the *irconcladd-0.33.0* tgz in *.../dists/quicklisp/archives/* with *ironclad-v0.34.tgz*
- the entry *dists/quicklisp/software/ironclad-0.33.0/* in *.../dists/quicklisp/installed/releases/ironclad.txt* with *dists/quicklisp/software/ironclad-v0.34/*.
- I also updated *ironclad.txt* and *ironclad-text.txt* in *.../dists/quicklisp/installed/systems/*

#### Well, it worked, but I only did it this way because I don't know any better (but am sure there has to be a better way).